# Multiple Knapsack Variations

Tags: algorithm, matrix, constraints, knapsack-problem

I'm and undergrad doing some evolutionary algorithm work on the multiple knapsack problem. I've completed my code, but I'm struggling to understand an aspect of test cases. I've noticed that they have a constraint (weights or costs) matrix, as opposed to a list. Why? Why should the cost of an object depend on which knapsack it's in? I can certainly add to the algorithm to make this happen, but I don't understand its applications. Each test case I've found is in this format. Any help with the matrix or data with 1-dimensial constraint would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean the multiple knapsack problem, or the multi-dimensional knapsack problem? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multi-dimensional_knapsack_problem for the variations. If you mean the multi-dimensional knapsack problem, then you have a matrix because each item is described by a multi-dimensional vector, so the list of items can then be seen as a matrix. If you mean the multiple knapsack problem, then I'm not sure what matrix you're referring to. Can you link to something where data is presented that way?

Comment: The test data I'm referring to is http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/orlib/files/mknap2.txt. It seems that this data is for the multi-dimensional knapsack problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a popular paper on the travelings salesman says:

> *The popularity of the travelings salesman problem does not originate from millions of salesman that want to calculate the optimal route.*

Based on your specification of the problem, I think you are talking about the [*Multiple-Choice Knapsack Problem*](http://www.diku.dk/~pisinger/95-1.pdf) (p. 12). With *P* the price matrix and *W* the weight matrix.

The same of course holds for the Knapsack problem. Although the story is about a knapsack that knapsack can be anything.

Take for instance a scheduling problem. Say you have a (fictitious)  hospital with three employees: two doctors and one nurse. Now each day, one makes a list of tasks these employees have to carry out (for instance examining patients, filling in forms,...). Now we can represent each of the employees as a knapsack since they have a limited number of hours they work that day.

The weight of a task describes the amount of time employee *i* needs to handle task *j*. And furthermore it can be used to specify that a certain task is forbidden. For instance in Belgium a nurse with an A-certificate is not allowed to give a patient an injection. You can enforce this by specifying that the nurse would take years to handle such task, the "weight" of that task is thus too large with respect to the capacity of that bag.

> So: *w<sub>ij</sub>* describes the time employee *i* spends to carry out task *j* and is set above the capacity if that task cannot be carried out by that employee.

Furthermore the value is for instance the quality of carrying out the task. If one of the doctors is specialized in heart diseases, evidently his diagnosis for patients with heart problems will be better. Or you can for instance use the inverse of the amount you need to pay the employee to handle that task (if the employees are paid on a *per-task* basis), to minimize the cost.

> So *p<sub>ij</sub>* specifies the quality with which employee *i* will carry out task *j*, or for instance the inverse of the cost of employee *i* carrying out task *j*.

The optimal configuration of the knapsack will thus specify which tasks the employees will handle that day such that no employee works more than is allowed (or performs tasks he/she is not licensed for), and furthermore optimizes the quality of service or minimizes the operational costs.

> So if *x<sub>ij</sub>*=1, that means in the optimal scenario, employee *i* will carry out task *j* that day.

A typical application is thus one where multiple employees/machines/servers handle tasks/problems/requests with different costs and bounds.

---

@IVlad made some constructive comments pointing to related problems:

- In the *Assignment problem*, one aims to construct a set of edges in a bipartite graph such that no two edges share a node and the total weight is maximized. One cannot (evidently) map the MCKP to the AP, since the weights will discard situations where an employee will perform too much tasks, simply because it is optimal.
- The multi-objective variant transforms the price matrix *P* into a tensor (or beyond) such that you have different evaluation criteria you can take into account (for instance both the quality and the price), and you search for an optimal solution for both objectives.

Comment: What you describe sounds like either an assignment problem or a multi-objective knapsack problem. It doesn't seem like the multiple knapsack problem however.

Comment: @IVlad: multi-objective means that their are different ways to evaluate a configuration. Here the only measure is the sum of the total value of all bags. About the assignment problem: you forgot that the weights play a part as well, these are not incorporated in the formal definition.

Comment: Multi-objective means there are multiple objectives, not different ways to evaluate a configuration. You would want to minimize how much you pay your doctors, maximize their assignment to tasks within their specialty and maximize the amount of jobs being done. For the assignment problem, you can assign costs as well as capacities to your graphs. AFAIK, the multiple knapsack problem is where you have multiple identical knapsacks that you must fill. Your problem does not deal with identical knapsacks if I understand it right. See for example http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter6.pdf

Comment: @IVlad: (1) Well the knapsack's can be identical - that doesn't change the problem - you can simply scale the weights up, so it's arbitrary if the capacity is the same or different. (2) based on the OP's description, I think he means the *Multiple-Choice KP* as defined [here](http://www.diku.dk/~pisinger/95-1.pdf), there is only one objective: maximizing the total value (you can choose the semantics of that value: profit, quality), but it remains one objective. It would be multi-objective if we were talking about a tensor... I indeed misformulated *multi-objective* a bit.

Comment: The problem from my assignment reads: "MULTIPLE KNAPSACK: Given n objects, each with a value vi and a weight wi, and k knapsacks, each with capacity C, assign objects to the knapsacks so that the total weight of the objects in each does not exceed C and the total value of all the selected objects is maximized." This implies to me that it is a simple form the problem. The issue arises when I search for test cases because they all seem to be for multiple dimensions. Thank you for helping me understand how the problem applies.

Comment: @joshua: the where does the matrix arises? Only *X*?

Comment: In my assignment description it doesn't. It arose in the test cases I was looking at for the multi-dimensional constraint knapsack problem. Now I suppose I'm looking for literature and test cases on a simpler form, the one-dimensional constraint multiple knapsack problem.

Comment: In my case the problem seems exactly like the 0/1 knapsack problem, except it has multiple knapsacks.

Answer (score 0):

> The test data I'm referring to is people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/orlib/files/mknap2.txt. It seems that this data is for the multi-dimensional knapsack problem.

This looks like data for the [multiconstraint 0/1 knapsack problem](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02242185#page-1): as you can see in that paper, there are `m` constraints:

```
Maximize 
              z = sum{j = 1 to n: c[j]*x[j]}
Subject to: 
              sum{j = 1 to n: a[i,j]*x[j]} <= b[i]     i = 1, ..., m    
                                                       x[j] in {0,1}
```

This is suggested by the following reference at the start of the data document you linked to:

> Simulated Annealing: A. Drexel (1988) "A Simulated Annealing
>    Approach to the Multiconstraint Zero-One Knapsack Problem."
>    Computing, 40:1-8.

And it seems to be the only thing that fits the data format.

Comment: Yes I now understand better the difference between the problems. According to the description of my problem I think I'm looking for a simpler 1-dimensional constraint multiple knapsack problem. I don't know that there are test cases for this problem though.

Comment: @joshua - I'm not aware of any test cases you could use, but it would be pretty easy to take test cases for a classic `0 / 1 knapsack` problem and use those. Compare results with those of a brute force solution.